# Apache Kafka Default Encoder Not Working

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Kafka 0.8 beta, and I am just trying to mess around with sending different objects, serializing them using my own encoder, and sending them to an existing broker configuration. For now I am trying to get just DefaultEncoder working.

I have the broker and everything setup and working for StringEncoder, but I am not able to get any other data type, including just pure byte[], to be sent and received by the broker.

My code for the Producer is:

```
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;


public class ProducerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long events = 5;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        rnd.setSeed(new Date().getTime());
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9093,localhost:9094");
        props.setProperty("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder");
        props.setProperty("partitioner.class", "example.producer.SimplePartitioner");
        props.setProperty("request.required.acks", "1");
        props.setProperty("producer.type", "async");
        props.setProperty("batch.num.messages", "4");

        ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
        Producer<byte[], byte[]> producer = new Producer<byte[], byte[]>(config);
        for (long nEvents = 0; nEvents < events; nEvents++) {
            byte[] a = "Hello".getBytes();
            byte[] b = "There".getBytes();

            KeyedMessage<byte[], byte[]> data = new KeyedMessage<byte[], byte[]>("page_visits", a, b);
            producer.send(data);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        producer.close();
    }
}
```

I used the same SimplePartitioner as in the example given [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example), and replacing all the byte arrays by Strings and changing the serializer to kafka.serializer.StringEncoder works perfectly.

For reference, SimplePartitioner:

```
import kafka.producer.Partitioner;
import kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties;

public class SimplePartitioner implements Partitioner<String> {
    public SimplePartitioner (VerifiableProperties props) {

    }

    public int partition(String key, int a_numPartitions) {
        int partition = 0;
        int offset = key.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (offset > 0) {
           partition = Integer.parseInt( key.substring(offset+1)) % a_numPartitions;
        }
       return partition;
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is that the partitioning class `SimplePartitioner` is applicable only for Strings. When I try to run the Producer asynchronously, it creates a separate thread that handles the encoding and partitioning before sending to the broker. This thread hits a roadblock when it realizes that SimplePartitioner works only for Strings, but because it's a separate thread, no Exceptions are thrown, and so the thread just exits without any indication of wrongdoing.

If we change the SimplePartitioner to accept byte[], for instance:

```
import kafka.producer.Partitioner;
import kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties;

public class SimplePartitioner implements Partitioner<byte[]> {
    public SimplePartitioner (VerifiableProperties props) {

    }

    public int partition(byte[] key, int a_numPartitions) {
        int partition = 0;
        return partition;
    }

}
```

This works perfectly now.

Comment: You should probably just stick to the default of kafka.producer.DefaultPartitioner for your partitioner.class property instead of hardcoding a particular return value for a partitioner.

Comment: This was meant as a test drive. But, here's a scenario where the default partitioner would not work: Suppose you want a particular subsequence of the messages to be consumed strictly in the order they are produced. This would fail miserably if you use the default partitioner because the default would just use the hash of the key, which is unpredictable. Instead, if you write your own custom partitioner, and there is some way to detect the subsequence, then we can assign them to the same partition. This exact use case occurred in my application.